# ¿Como pasar un sitio de un entorno de pruebas (sitio de ensayo) a un entorno en producción (sitio de producción)?

Tags: wordpress

Tengo una web en un hosting pero esta en un sitio de ensayo con una url, necesito pasar el contenido a un sitio en producción con otra ulr diferente.
Ambos sitios proporcionadas dentro del mismo hosting
 Ejemplo:

sitio: producción: dominio.com

sitio: pruebas: 6cf.9f5.myftpuploadejemplo.com

¿Como se puede pasar el sitio del ambiente pruebas al de producción?, ¿Si se puede hacer el montaje sin plugin, en donde esta la opción para hacer el cambio dentro de wordpress y si es necesario el plugin, cual es el adecuado?

Comment: Depende mucho de las herramientas: tienes acceso de consola? o sólo FTP? algún gestor gráfico de archivos? Para la base: puedes duplicar la base? Tienes phpMyAdmin?

Comment: ftp si pero no tengo permitido subir los contenidos, y en modo grafico no encuentro la opción,

Comment: Entonces el administrador debería darte permisos para el mismo usuario, de subir los contenidos al otro espacio FTP. Y respecto a la base, qué herramientas tienes? El plugin que mencionas, para qué es y de cuál estamos hablando?

Comment: si eso voy a contactar, lo del plugin era una pregunta de si era necesario o no

Comment: si tienes claridad para qué usas "el plugin" tú mismo lo puedes contestar, supongo

Comment: cuando mencionas que es "el mismo hosting" es la misma empresa solamente o es la misma cuenta para los dos sitios? en ese último caso, tú no tienes acceso al panel de control? y te reitero la pregunta: tienes acceso de consola o shell?

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente sigo este procedimiento:

1. Realizar una copia de seguridad de la base de datos
2. Realizar una copia de seguridad de los archivos
3. Crear el directorio y restaurar los archivos
4. Crear la base de datos y restaurar la copia de
   seguridad
5. Actualizar los parámetros de credenciales de base de datos
6. Actualizar los parámetros de la dirección del sitio
7. Realizar ajustes particulares de nuestra instalación

Dejé documentado cada paso en http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com.ar/2013/10/copiar-WordPress.html

Cualquier duda avisame. .Estoy realizando un pasaje en este momento siguiendo ese procedimiento y he realizado muchos pasajes en forma similar.

Nota: puede que algunas herramientas varíen según el hosting.

Saludos!